# docker SSL connection error

Tags: ssl, https, docker

Im new to Docker and have been experimenting with running different apps in containers (with some success). Currently im trying to run an app (ajenti) that requires https on a different port

for example

> https://example.com:8000

everything will startup just fine. however when I try to connect to through browser I get the error

> SSL connection error
>
> Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.

I'm not sure where the problem is, is it on the docker host or the docker container?

anyone have experience with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone interested, issue was on the docker container. I needed to generate a ssh key

as it turns out I could login into ajenti via http (with warnings) then generate key in config options

alternatively I could have attached to container and generated ssh key

Comment: how is ssh connected with ssl? these are two different things.